# Converting JSON strings to Parquet format using AWS EMR

Tags: java, apache-spark, amazon-emr, parquet

I have JSON strings that I fetch from a service. I need to convert that data to Parquet format. I have the Spark schema for the JSON strings, but I have no idea where to start since this is my first time dealing with AWS EMR and big data in general:

- Can I submit the job to EMR spark cluster from my service, or do I have to create a step with a JAR file created with the script to do the conversion after uploading the JSON files into S3?
- Should I create the EMR cluster in my service using AWS SDK or create the EMR cluster first through the console? I tried creating an EMR cluster from the console with the default settings, but the cluster terminates as soon as I created it with the message "terminated by user". There isn't any cloudwatch logs to understand why the cluster is terminating by itself. I looked at other SO questions regarding this issues, and made sure that auto terminate is not enabled.
- Should I aggregate all the JSONs into a single file and submit that file to spark, or I can submit the jsons one by one and create a single parquet file from that data?
- Anything else I need to take into consideration?

I am really confused and it seems like my research abilities are failing me. I can't find anything relevant to help me understand how to approach this problem. Any help (including comments to references) is most welcome and highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sparkSQL to read first the JSON file into an DataFrame, then writing the DataFrame as parquet file.

```
val df = spark.read.json("path/to/json/file")   //in json path you can directly give file like below
        or
val jsonString = $json
val df = spark.read.json(jsonString)
```

And converting df to parquet you can use below code:

```
df.write.parquet("path/to/parquet/file")

or

df.save("path/to/parquet/file", "parquet")
```

So, for converting a json string to parquet. You can put all together your code in project and create a JAR of it.

After creating JAR you can put that in EMR and run a spark-submit command of it.

To Schedule it at a particular time you can use lambda to trigger it.